# Can't open a new window from an href with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, href, html

Here's the issue: On a webpage I have two `HREF`. One which points to server A (i.e. https://mydomainA.com) and the second points to server B (i.e. https://mydomainB.com). Both `HREF` have a target of `_blank`. The first one works like a charm and the second one doesn't work at all.

Of course, both work just fine in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. The second link (https://mydomainB.com) also works when I manually enter the address into the nav bar, so the connection with the server is not under question here.

I'm pretty sure the issue is related to some security setting within IE but I wanted to know if any of you ever encounter that kind of issue and how you managed to resolve it.

I can't change my IE security setting since the machine is controlled by the IT team.

Comment: Can u try `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://mydomainb.com/')">Link</a>` ?

Comment: Thanks @Yuriy Galanter. Unfortunately, when I try with an `onclick`, a second window open but instead of opening the proper URL (https://mydomainb.com/), the second window load the same page as the first one. I end up having the same page opens on two windows (which could be expected to a certain point since I used `#` as the `HREF`). Now if I use `javascript:void(0);` instead of `#`, the second window try to load `javascript:void(0);` as a URL... Dargn IE... Any other idea? Thanks